# Grouping DataSet of different classes in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

Is it possible to groupByKey two DataSet of different classes such that the result is

> key -> Array ([Class1 instance], [Class2 instance], [Class2
> instance])

To clarify the question, here is simple scala code.

```
object DataSetGrouping {

  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  import java.sql.Timestamp

  case class Loan(loanId: String, principalAmount: Double)
  case class Payment(loanId: String, paymentAmount: Double, paymentDate: Timestamp)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("DataSetGrouping").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val loanData = Seq(
      Loan("loan1", 30000),
      Loan("loan2", 60000)).toDS()

    val paymentsData = Seq(
      Payment("loan1", 10000, date("2017-07-31")),
      Payment("loan1", 10000, date("2017-08-31")),
      Payment("loan2", 20000, date("2017-07-31")),
      Payment("loan2", 20000, date("2017-08-31"))).toDS()

    val paymentMap = paymentsData.map(p => (p.loanId, p))
    val loanMap = loanData.map(l => (l.loanId, l))

    paymentMap.show()
    loanMap.show()
  }

  def date(date: String): Timestamp = {
    return java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(date + "T00:00:00"))
  }

}
```

Is it possible to group these two data set so that the result is as following?

> loan1 -> [ Loan("loan1",...), Payment("loan1",...),
> Payment("loan1",...) ],
>
> loan2 -> [ Loan("loan2",...),
> Payment("loan2",...), Payment("loan2",...) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you can get without dealing with Kryo `Encoder` and `Any` is probably something like this:

```
paymentsData.groupByKey(_.loanId).mapGroups { 
  case (id, xs) => (id, xs.toSeq) 
}.toDF("loanID", "payments").join(loanData, Seq("loanID"))

+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|loanID|payments                                                                      |principalAmount|
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|loan1 |[[loan1,10000.0,2017-07-31 00:00:00.0], [loan1,10000.0,2017-08-31 00:00:00.0]]|30000.0        |
|loan2 |[[loan2,20000.0,2017-07-31 00:00:00.0], [loan2,20000.0,2017-08-31 00:00:00.0]]|60000.0        |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Quite expensive due to grouping.